# RelativeLayout "Couldn't resolve resource..." Android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

When using the below code, I get an error "Couldn't resolve resource @id/item1" Why is this? id/item1 is added before I use it, so I'm not sure why this is coming up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/noimage" />
    <TextView         
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:padding="3dip" 
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item1"/>
    <TextView         
        android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Content"
        android:padding="3dip" 
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/item1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't have this error with your code.

Make sure you don't have errors in other resources (layouts, values, drawables, etc.). And then clean/refresh/build the project

Comment: I had the same error and was able to fix it by restarting eclipse (cleaning didn't help). Although for me the graphical relative layout editor crashed while I was dragging stuff around.

Comment: when in doubt... restart eclipse. the answer to probably half of my android-related problems -_-

Comment: For those using Android Studio and cleaning didn't help, restarting fixed the problem for me too.

Comment: Same here, tried Build>Clean Project + Build>Make Project or Build>Rebuild Project - nothing helped.
Restarting Android Studio fixed it.

Answer (score 14):

As Jose said, sometimes Android Studio just gets crazy.  But a restart ain't always enough.

Invalidate your caches and restart.

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart

[image: Menu Selection]
[image]

Wait until AS has completely restarted and rebuilt.  Hopefully it'll behave logically.

Answer (score 1):

RelativeLayout “Couldn't resolve resource… ... you need to define String Resources in res/values/strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error when I import a project form other devices.
Sometimes, the reason of this error is the wrong android SDK path in your current developing environment.

[image]

You need change your local android SDK path.

1 Open local.properties

[image]

2 Replace the sdk.dir path use your local SDK path.

[image]

3 Refresh your project and Close your Android Studio.

[image]

4 Open the Android Studio, Everything is OK.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem on 2 computers with Android Studio. Helped to open Gradle and re-sync the project (shown on the screenshot posted previously) 
[image: Resync]

Answer (score 0):

Some times the IDE gets crazy. :) Just restart the Android Studio, as said before by @JasonAxelson, @AlexLockwood, @craned and @PhilippGächter.

Answer (score -1):

This happens when you forget to save the /res/values/strings.xml