# Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/homebackground

Tags: android, android-drawable

I created a new project in **Android Lollipop** (API 21) using Studio(64) and Java 7. When I try to add a background on main layout (relative layout) I am getting error

[image]

My res folder structure is

[image]

NOTE: I have placed 720x1280 img in all drawable* folders.

My XML is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/homebackground">

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried using PNG / JPG.. but still I am getting same error. **Can someone tell where am I going wrong ?**

---

I referred these, but they are not related to my problem or don't solve my problem

[Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/backround.png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542573/couldnt-resolve-resource-drawable-backround-png)

[RelativeLayout "Couldn't resolve resource..." Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390733/relativelayout-couldnt-resolve-resource-android)

[Android image can't convert to drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358776/android-image-cant-convert-to-drawable)

Comment: Try to delete your homebackgraond.jpg from just drawable folder.

Comment: This may sound odd, but regardless of the error, does the project compile and run?

Comment: @BasilMiller : Did that, sill the problem exists

Comment: @Melquiades **Compile** - `Yes`, **Run** - `Yes, but no background`

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Android Studio, clicking on File > Invalidate caches/restart should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Manifest file .....in the field where there is **@drawable/homeground** replace that with **@android:drawable/homeground**

Answer (score 0):

I tried "invalidate caches/restart" but it didn't work for me. So to solve this I moved my image(night_sky.jpg) from drawable to mipmap folder and the error was gone.
It worked for me hope it will work for you also

**Image for reference:**

[image: image for reference]